# APT-GET: Does APT-GET store its # updates somewhere?

Tags: apt

When I am using apt-get, and often times when I login via `ssh` I get a statement that:

```
X upgraded, Y newly installed, Z to remove and A not upgraded.
```

(Obviously X, Y, Z, A are replaced with the relevant numbers).

Is there a place or a file where these are kept?  The shell seems to know when I login, and I scoured the motd files to no avail.

Is there anything on the system that I can get to in order to determine if the machine has an update waiting?

The context for the request: I want to use it as an exercise to modify my [powerline-shell](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell) and I don't want to do something taxing, since the prompt call needs to stay fast-moving.  If those variables can be found and are `>0` then I am good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a file that it keeps that information in, but this may interest you:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -s | grep "not\ upgraded"`

This will print:

`1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.`

You can continue to get these down to what you want using the `cut` command:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -s | grep "not\ upgraded" | cut -c 1-1"`

This will give you just `1`, or the first character in that sequence. If this does not equal 0, then you have updates! Simple as that, you can continue expanding to put the following in a script in /usr/bin :

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMUPG=`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -s | grep "not\ upgraded" | cut -c 1-1`
if [[ "$NUMUPG" == "0" ]]
then echo "SYSTEM UP-TO-DATE"
  else echo "SYSTEM OUT-OF-DATE"
fi
exit 0
```

If you create the script, be sure to do `chmod +x [FILENAME]` before attempting to run it.

Hope that helps! If it does, +1 me!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using something that will cause a delay, since the prompt is "rerun" in python every time you hit a new line.  I use something similar to your proposal in conky, but I am looking for something quicker.  Also trying to avoid using cron to write a separate file.

Comment: @chow, then you can apply a little more scripting to test if it has been run in the last x minutes already, and skip it if it has.